# how are tarot cards,horoscope,and readings aginst God and scripture?

Tags: bible

how is it that tarotcards and horoscopes and readings are against scripture?
if one doesn't believe in them but uses for warnings or educational purposes,or fun?  help!  i have loved one that goes on line for horoscope readings,thru tarot cards and owns some. how, in love, do i  show her, its against God, Jesus,and scripture?  Help, help help! and they are fundlementalist babtist.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

These things, and in turn people who practice these things are detestable to the LORD.

> "When you enter the land the Lord your God is giving you, do not learn to imitate the detestable ways of the nations there. Let no one be found among you who sacrifices his son or daughter in the fire, who practices divination or sorcery, interprets omens, engages in witchcraft, or casts spells, or who is a medium or spiritist or who consults the dead. Anyone who does these things is detestable to the Lord." (Deuteronomy 18:9-12 NIV)

Not only is it detestable to the LORD, but to take it a step further...

> Leviticus 20:6, "I will set my face against the person who turns to mediums and spiritists to prostitute himself by following them. I will cut him off from his people."

... and ultimately, it leads to death.

> 1 Chronicles 10:13-14, NIV. "Saul died because he was unfaithful to the Lord; he did not keep the word of the Lord and even consulted a medium for guidance, and did not inquire of the Lord."